# Using Appengine, connect to a different Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

So I have 2 app engine projects.

In one of my app engines, I have a google cloud storage component with it. Usually to connect to those cloud storage files I just do:

```
<?php
   use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

   $document_data = "123";
   $object_url = 'gs://{bucket}/FOLDER/file.ext';
   $options = stream_context_create(['gs'=>['acl'=>'private']]);
   $my_file = fopen($object_url, 'w', false, $options);
   fwrite($my_file, $document_data);
   fclose($my_file);
?>
```

or

```
<?php file_get_contents('gs://FOLDER/file.ext'); ?>
```

I have another app engine with no google cloud storage but i'd like to connect to the cloud storage in my other app engine.

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give bucket permissions to the App Engine application as follows:

1. Go to the Storage browser section in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).
2. Select your bucket, click on the 3 vertical dots and click on 'Edit bucket permissions'.
3. Click on 'Add new', select 'User' and select at least WRITER permissions. Type your App Engine service account in the text field. The App Engine service account has the format: `<projectID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`
4. Save the changes.

After these steps you should be able to connect to a bucket that belongs to another project.

Comment: Thanks! So by doing this I should be able to access the bucket like my above code?

Comment: Yes, you should. I was able to do it with your code from one App Engine application to a bucket that belongs to another project following the steps I posted.